# How do we lock down the docker terminal

Tags: security, docker, boot2docker

We have a application running a number of containers within the docker machine. To start it, we use the docker terminal. However anyone with access to the host machine can run docker machines, start and stop containers or load new containers

How do we lock down access to the docker terminal such that only authorised users can run commands

Comment: that's why we have the concept of docker group, right?

Comment: One of our requirements is it to be portable between windows and linux hosts. How would docker group work on a windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

It's worse than that.  Anyone who can run any Docker command at all can run:

```
docker run -it -v /:/host -u root ubuntu sh
```

And then they will have a root-level shell that has unrestricted access to the host's filesystem.

There's no (easy) way to restrict this further.  You can't safely make Docker access available to untrusted users on a shared system.

A typical setup has the Docker socket owned by root and a dedicated "docker" group and isn't world-accessible.  If you have a limited number of users that already have sudo access (or you don't mind if they give it to themselves) they can `sudo run docker`, or you can add them to the "docker" group, and other users won't be able to run Docker commands; they can access services in already-running containers.  (If you've changed the Docker daemon setup so that it listens on a TCP socket, you've given root access to the host to anyone who can reach the socket.)

In the specific case of Docker Machine, it always listens on a TCP socket, and while it's not accessible off-host, the only way you can restrict access to it is by limiting distribution of its TLS certificates.  I probably wouldn't use it in an environment other than a development system where I can't use a "more native" Docker.

Comment: does that mean if we want to restrict a user from accessing a container, the only way is to remove him from the sudoers file?

Comment: If they can `docker run`, they can put themselves back.  If your core workflow involves `docker exec` then anyone who can “access a container” has root on the system.

Comment: the sudoer file that I was talking about is on host. So, what I am trying to say is if a user is not in the docker group and neither in the sudoer file (of the host), he cannot do `docker run` or `docker exec`, right?

Comment: That is correct.  (They could still “access a container” via its published TCP ports, but that’s presumably normal operation.)